# Cmd+backtick strange behavior with multiple spaces

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-el-capitan

I'm configuring a new MacBook Pro and I'm seeing a strange behavior using the keys <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

Supposing I have the following disposition:

- Space 1:

  - 2 Atom windows
  - 3 Chrome windows
- Space 2

  - 1 Atom window
  - 1 Chrome window

On the old machine if I use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> on a Chrome window from space 1, it'll only rotate between the 3 Chrome windows for that space, but on the new machine it's rotating between the 4 Chrome windows.

There's any configuration to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a little bit more, I tried to reboot the machine and this solved the problem.